# jQuery drag and drop between two tables

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, coffeescript, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I want to drag and drop between multiple table rows.

As per the requirement, I should be able to drag categories to a product and vice versa. I am able to drag and drop multiple rows to tables. But somehow dragged items are being appended to source table instead of expected table. Below is my code.

Comment: Mind giving us compiled HTML?

Comment: Thanks to all, I've fixed this issue by moving sortable(helper) code to droppable.